# How do I install a bz2.bz2 file?

Tags: wireless, drivers

I need to install the driver for my wireless card (hp pavilion g6) in order to get wireless working on my computer.

Problem is (as far as I can tell) it's not a tar.bz2 and none of the instructions for that appear to be working. I've extracted it (through Ubuntu Archive) down to a .tar file, but that file doesn't appear to work at all either.

the file name is:

2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO_v2.bz2.bz2

How do I install my drivers using this kind of file?

Comment: .tar itself is an archive. Have you tried to extract the .tar file?

Comment: No. Extract Here says invalid archive type. Won't open it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click the .tar file and select "Extract Here". Open the file `os/linux/config.mk` with any text editor and change `HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=n` to `HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=y`. Proofread, save and close the text editor.

Install the prerequisites:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
```

Now compile the driver.

```
cd Desktop/2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO  # or wherever you extracted the folder
sudo su
make
make install
modprobe rt5390sta
exit
```

Be sure the conflicting driver isn't loaded:

```
lsmod | grep rt28
```

If rt2800pci is loaded, it should be blacklisted:

```
sudo su
echo "blacklist rt2800pci"  >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

If you get an error at `make`, stop and ask us.

Comment: Thank you for that, however when I click extract here it tells me the archive format is invalid

Comment: Please try this version. It's a zip that can be extracted directly: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/58267392/2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO.zip

Comment: Thank you for your help thus far. Here is the pastbin of my progress/error code now:
http://pastebin.com/shT60sjb

Comment: Do you have linux-headers installed matching your running kernel version? sudo dpkg -s linux-headers-`uname -r` | head -n3 Those tickmarks are on the left side of my US keyboard on the same key with ~. If not,please install and try again: sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`

Answer (score 0):

you can extract a `.bz2` file by the command:

```
bzip2 -d myfile.bz2
```