# Ubuntu 13.04 Ralink rt5390 won't work after upgrade,

Tags: wireless, drivers, 13.04, ralink

I Have an HP 2000 Notebook dualboot with Win7 and Ubuntu 13.04. After I upgraded from 12.10, the wireless network detects wifi but when I try connecting It wont do anything.

I try doing stuff from those websites
[How do I install a bz2.bz2 file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219113/how-do-i-install-a-bz2-bz2-file/303410#303410)
But I get errors at make
and from here
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2138302
But since I'm barely new here I don't know how to make the patch to work.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Combining a couple of answers from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2138302)

From answer #4

1. download driver http://www.mediatek.com/_en/07_downloads/01-1_windowsDetail.php?sn=5001
2. `tar -xvf /home/ukbeast/USERNAME/Downloads/2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO_v2.bz2.bz2`
3. `cd 2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO`
4. download patch http://gridlox.net/diff/rt5592sta_fix_64bit_3.8.patch
5. `patch -p1 <rt5592sta_fix_64bit_3.8.patch` (if asks for directory point it to <s>rt_linux_dev.c</s> rt_linux.c)
6. make sure /os/linux/config.mk reads HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=y
7. `make`
8. `sudo make install`
9. `modprobe rt5390sta`

and from answer #6

10.`sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

At the end of the file, add these lines:

```
# Blacklist conflicting kernel modules
blacklist rt2800pci
blacklist rt2800lib
blacklist rt2x00usb
blacklist rt2x00pci
blacklist rt2x00lib
blacklist rt2860sta
blacklist rt3090sta
```

I do not know if this will work, but it may be worth a shot. :D

Comment: from the patch part, how do i point to that directory? that the part I don't understand. I'm new here sorry.

Comment: The path is inside the unpacked package. so if you unpacked it in your Downloads folder the path would be `Downloads/2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO/os/linux/config.mk`

Comment: Well i mean I type this `patch -p1 <rt5592sta_fix_64bit_3.8.patch` and it says something about a directory not found. Is it me that Im typing it wrong or what?

Comment: After a bit of an experement: `File to patch: /home/YOUR_USERNAME/Downloads/2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO/os/linux/rt_linux.c **I really hope this works after all this!!**

Comment: Link Update http://www.mediatek.com/en/downloads/rt539x-pcie/, not sure if it is the same.

Comment: I have a Ralink rt5390 on a HP Pavilion G7 1116sg, regrettably this made no difference after following all steps. Admittedly there is a weak wifi signal but every other device ranging from an samsung to intel seems to manage fine.

Answer (score 0):

For kernel>3.8 (Ubuntu 13.10, 14.04) run **`make`** leads to errors.

For fix this problem:

5.1 In file *`include/os/rt_linux.h`* type of variable **`int`** `fsuid` and **`int`** `fsgid` in **`struct _OS_FS_INFO_`** change to:

```
typedef struct _OS_FS_INFO_
 {

    kuid_t          fsuid;
    kgid_t          fsgid;

    mm_segment_t    fs;
 } OS_FS_INFO;
```