# Wifi adaptor isn't recognized by Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.10, internet, hp-pavilion

I have an Pavilion G6-1d80NR with a Realtek RTL8188CE WiFi card. I just recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 alongside Windows 7 and aside from having to tweak the nomodest setting from the Ubuntu setup screen, the installation was smooth. But for some reason Ubuntu doesn't recognize the network card. It's not even finding it when I look at the computer overview. I can't even turn on wireless capability from the network settings. In Windows 7 I can browse the web fine, just not in Ubuntu. Any ideas as to how I can fix this? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please do what is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Answer (score 0):

You might have to install the driver from Realtek in order to make it work. Some network adapters have special functions or configurations that require the OS to use a specific driver (like for extra frequency ranges).
In the case of your network adapter, Realtek provides a driver for Linux-based operating systems like Ubuntu; and since you are using version 13.10, you need to download the version for Linux kernels above 2.6.24 from this page: http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=272&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true#RTL8188CE
(It jumps to your adapter automatically, but it takes a few seconds for the page to load completly)

Comment: Thanks! Just transfer it via flash drive? Also the key for turning the network card on or off doesn't work. I'm assuming that has to do with the driver too?

Comment: Just found out the specs I previously found for this laptop were incorrect pertaining to the network card. Sorry for the mix up. The card I have is the Ralink RT5390. While I've seen posts where people say Ubuntu drivers are offered by Ralink, I haven't found any that work nor have I found the drivers on the Ralink website. I tried following this http://askubuntu.com/questions/303415/ubuntu-13-04-ralink-rt5390-wont-work-after-upgrade but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: I've found a thread (http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/wlan-auf-asus-a73s-laptop-einrichten/#post-2960487) on a german forum that seemingly solves the problem for your exact wifi card. You simply have to download the tarball at the end of the post and excute the commands in the first code section (you might have to alter the path in the 4th command to your download folder).