# rt5390 driver ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ralink

How can I install the wlan driver for my rt5390 in ubuntu 14.04

I have already tried this link but no help.
http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/02/how-to-install-drivers-for-ralink.html

Comment: That guide is for 11.10. **NEVER** use guides for old versions, it is highly probable that they will break your system, especially when they are *that* old. Unfortunately with Ralink is always a guess whether they support Linux or not (most of the time is no, BTW). Try to follow [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/303422/29595) combined with [this other answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/463040/29595) to make it work. If doesn't work, try using [this GitHub](https://github.com/agerwick/RT28XX-RT539X-Linux-driver) package.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I've done on my own system.
It works better than original driver.

1. download archive : https://github.com/Inglebard/2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO_v2/raw/master/2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO_v2.tar.bz2.bz2
2. extract archive
3. cd 2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO
4. download : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Inglebard/2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO_v2/master/patch/rt5592sta_fix_64bit_3.8.patch
5. patch -p1

   make sure /os/linux/config.mk reads HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=y

   make

   sudo make install

   modprobe rt5390sta

You may need to to install and configure dkms to build automaticaly wifi drivers when kernel change : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DKMS

You may need to disable some other drivers in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

```
## Blacklist conflicting kernel modules
blacklist rt2800pci
blacklist rt2800lib
blacklist rt2x00usb
blacklist rt2x00pci
blacklist rt2x00lib
blacklist rt2860sta
blacklist rt3090sta
```

**Note :** I don't know why but sometimes (it's happens rarely), driver is unable to find wifi hotspot and write this in syslog :

```
GetDesiredTssiAndCurrentTssi: BBP TSSI INFO is not ready. (BbpR47 = 0x94)
RT5390_AsicTxAlcGetAutoAgcOffset: Incorrect desired TSSI or current TSSI
```

And you may have to shutdown by power button of your machine. (If someone know why, I'am interressed)

Answer (score 1):

The patch line should be:

patch -p1 <rt5592sta_fix_64bit_3.8.patch

This editor confuses < and leaves out the rest of the line :-)

Also see: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2137576&page=2

Thanks for the links, wasn't able to find available files